# Undefined reference to constructor of local struct

Tags: templates, struct

I have the following code:

```
    template<typename T>
    void addGeneric(const T & val) { 
        struct Item 
        { 
            Item();
             T & value; 
            ~Item(); 
        }; 
        Item* item = new Item; // Error appear on this line
        item->value = val; 

        void* ptr = item;
        array.push_back(ptr);
    };
```

And i get the following error:

> Error: undefined reference to `void GenericArray::addGeneric(std::string const&)::Item::Item()'

I don't understand why i get it, or how i can resolve it. Help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you literally didn't define them, you just declared that there is a constructor and a destructor, but you don't implement/define them.

Anyway, your example could do w/o the constructor/destructor;-)

```
template<typename T>
void addGeneric(const T & val) { 
    struct Item 
    { 
        Item(){
             /* do something constructive here...or simply ommit the entire constructor */
         }

         T & value; 
        ~Item(){
              /* destroy what you have created! ...or simply ommit the entire destructor too */
        } 
    }; 
    Item* item = new Item; // Error appear on this line
    item->value = val; 

    void* ptr = item;
    array.push_back(ptr);
};
```

Comment: but when i do it a got the following errors: In instantiation of 'GenericArray::addGeneric(const T&)::Item::Item() [with T = std::basic_string<char>]':
error: uninitialized reference member in 'class std::basic_string<char>&' [-fpermissive]
note: 'std::basic_string<char>& GenericArray::addGeneric(const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]::Item::value' should be initialized

Comment: Yes, now I see it, seems to be because you've used the reference (&) sign; that, indeed, needs to be initialized in that form, but in your case, you could simply do without, but a copy will occur. Or you'll have to pass it with a constructor parameter: or changing it to a pointer (*) instead. I see that nothing gets copied, so that will mean that you'll have to keep your original data alive somewhere else :-) (unless you simply remove the reference (&) from your value variable...)